# What is the correct syntax for a data-action attribute to respond to a StimulusJS CustomEvent?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have a Rails ViewComponent with the following markup

```
# my_componenet.html.erb
<div data-controller="my-component">
    
    <%= file_field_tag "name", "data-action": "my-component#changed" >

    <%= tag.div "data-my-component-target": "mytarget", 
         "data-action": "my-event->my-component#triggered" do %>    
    <% end %>

</div>
```

In the stimulus controller

```
# my_component_controller.js 
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

    static targets = ["mytarget"]
    
    event() {
        const event = new CustomEvent("my-event")
        console.log("event initialized: ", event)
        return event
    }

    changed() {
        this.mytargetTarget.dispatchEvent(this.event())
    }
    
    triggered() {
        console.log("event received")
    }

}
```

The browser console is showing "event initialized", but I cannot get "event received" to be displayed.

What is the correct way to respond to a custom event in a Stimulus controller? Or what is the best way to debug issues like this? (I thought that I could use monitorEvents($0) to confirm "my-event"
is properly dispatched, but it's not giving me much of use. I'm not sure of this is the problem, or if I'm doing something wrong")

Comment: `<div data-my-component-target="mytarget" data-action="my-event->my-component#triggered"></div>`

Comment: thanks @Alex, the quotes on the data attributes were a copy-paste error. Apologies. Does everything else OK with my code? It would be useful to confirm this as it means the problem lies elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: should work, check if you have `my-event` event listener on that div.

Answer (score 1):

Stimulus recommends using [Events when wanting to communicate](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#cross-controller-coordination-with-events) from one controller to another. It is less useful to use events when coordinating behaviour internally within one controller's instance.

It is not super clear on your goal here, so you may be better of avoiding events all together if not required. However, let's assume that your goal is to ensure that ALL instances of a controller can somehow work together or be in sync when ONE triggers some behaviour.

### About `CustomEvent`

I recommend you take a moment to read the entirety of the MDN page on what is a `CustomEvent` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

The MDN docs do a great job of breaking things down technically but it is still approachable. At the core, the behaviour you want to do is purely DOM Event driven and Stimulus is just a bit of sugar on top of event listeners.

The key part here is that events can bubble but do not by default, bubbling allows listeners to pick up events from their children.

### About `data-action`

When you use `data-action="my-event->my-controller#myMethod"` you are really just saying `someElement.addEventListener('my-event', (event) => { this/*controller*/.myMethod(event);})`. There is a bit more under the hood, including auto clean up of listeners, but that is generally it.

### Using `this.dispatch`

The `this.dispatch` method described here https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#cross-controller-coordination-with-events is the best way to dispatch an event from your controller. It auto bubbles and avoids you creating your own CustomEvent.

```html
<div data-controller="my-component">
  <field name="file" data-action="my-component#changed" type="file" />
  <div data-my-component-target="mytarget" data-action="my-event->my-component#triggered">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
# my_component_controller.js 
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["mytarget"]

  changed() {
    this.dispatchEvent('my-event', { target: this.mytargetTarget })
  }
    
  triggered() {
    console.log("event received")
  }
}
```

Note: As a general tip, it's good to remember that not everyone uses Ruby on Rails and for quicker answers it helps use only HTML in your examples. Unless the problem is Rails specific, it can help if the question is as bare-bones as possible.